# How to determine the output space of neural-network when performing time-series prediction

Tags: neural-network, time-series

Consider this toy example to illustrate a common situation (notice this is not necessarily related to NLP, please see edit for more details):
Alice and Bob are having a conversation, where each participant at each time-step says one word. The task is to predict what will be Bob's second next word.

The way I see this, there are a few basic types for a predictor (In this question - neural network).

1) the output at time-step *t* is what Bob said at *t+2* (scalar). Meaning: Only care about our target mission.

2) the output at time-step *t* is what Bob said at *t+1, t+2* (vector with two entries). Meaning: Only look at our target Bob, but adding information about his previous actions.

3) the output at time-step *t* is what Alice and Bob said at *t+2* (vector with two entries). Meaning: Adding Alice's true future action.

4) the output at time-step *t* is what Alice and Bob said at *t+1, t+2* (A matrix of 2x2). Meaning : Use every information available to describe the situation as best as possible.

Which one of the cases above is best suited? Just noting again that I only care about Bob's second word, and that precision is most important for evaluation.

**EDIT**

This is just an example to simplify what I believe is a common principal in question, and has nothing to do with natural language. To wrap your minds around it - instead of words as inputs the predictor might receive images of Alice's and Bob's eyebrows, and predicts according to that what will be Bob's second word.

**EDIT 2**
(There is no formulation because I do not have enough reputation for it).

My task is a regression problem, using neural network to take an input x of dimensions [*Batch, SeqLen, Features*], to approximate some function *f(x|l)*. For example, if *SeqLen=10*, and *l=100*, then *x* has 10 consecutive samples and *f(x|l=100)* is some value at 100 time-steps ahead.

Converting from the toy example, by denoting one of the feature - *feature_i*, as our target value (e.i. *f(x|l)*), then:

- *feature_i_l* is Bobs word at *t+l*.
- *feature_j_l* is Alices word at *t+l*.
- *feature_k_l* is the direction Bobs hair is moving by the wind at *t+l*.
- *f(x|l)* is Bobs word at *t+l*.

1) groundTruth is (*feature_i_l*).

2) groundTruth is (*feature_i_1, feature_i_2,...,feature_i_l*).

3) groundTruth is (*feature_j_l, feature_i_l*).

4) groundTruth is the entire features from *t* up to *t+l*.

Any model that requires performing, for 100 time-steps ahead, 100 prediction for *t+1*, then *t+2* and so on, the accumulating error will be huge.

Comment: Predict Bob’s next word. Then, predict it again. This is called Language Modeling

Comment: @SamH. I've edited the question and in the last paragraph of the edit part I've mentioned why this method does not work for my use-case

Comment: StackOverflow's format encourages specificity about the problem you face. Could you add a bit more to the "Just to clarify my use case" section? Are you doing an NLP problem, or time-series modeling? Are you regressing over the value at t+100, or are you using regression to predict the value at t+100?

Comment: @SamH. I've updated the question, although I think my first example is better because I am asking about a principal - If we have ground-truth data that spans a large space, but we are only interested to predict a specific sub-space of it, how much do we use? Only the relevant sub-space? The entire space? A sub-space that spans the relevant sub-space? 
I believe this is more a question of concept, rather than specific example, and I believe this question is extremely relevant to a lot of people, in different contexts.